# Lines are visible on a Multi-res / Subdivided model

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, baking

I've just subdivided and smoothed a model to increase it's poly count - It was relatively low res to begin with. And now I'm trying to use a Multires modifier to add details, which I can then bake into a normal map.

Unfortunately I seem to be getting these lines all over the model, which become more prominent at higher levels of Multires. These artifacts are also being baked into the normal map.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you've subdivided it with a simple subdivide operation instead of a Subdivision Surface modifier? If so, it has added edge loops but it has not rounded the shape, these edges loops will tend to flatten the faces, so maybe first try to Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide, then if you really need to subdivide before your Multires, do it with the Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: please share your object so that we can take a look

Comment: I think that explains it to be honest, thank you so much!